# Multiple Custom Validators for One ClientValidationFunction Messing up Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 4 text boxes for searching 2 different date columns of a table.  (The user can put a range for each column).  Using any date is completely optional, because  of this I created 4 CustomValidators to use the same ClientValidationFunction.  (I can't use a Range or Required Validator because they are optional).  Here is the custom function:

```
function ValidateDateRange(s, args) {
        var startDate;
        var endDate;
        var conToValSplit = document.getElementById(s.controltovalidate).id.split("_");
        var controlToValidate = conToValSplit[conToValSplit.length - 1];

        switch (controlToValidate) {
            case "txtFirstStartDate":
                startDate = document.getElementById("<%= txtFirstStartDate.ClientID %>").value;
                endDate = args.Value;
                break;
            case "txtSecondStartDate":
                startDate = args.value;
                endDate = document.getElementById("<%= txtSecondStartDate.ClientID %>").value;
                break;
            case "txtSecondEndDate":
                startDate = document.getElementById("<%= txtSecondEndDate.ClientID %>").value;
                endDate = args.Value;
                break;
            default:
                startDate = args.Value;
                endDate = document.getElementById("<%= txtFirstEndDate.ClientID %>").value;
                break;
        }

        if (new Date(args.Value) == "Invalid Date"){
            $(s).text("Please enter a valid end date(mm/dd/yyyy).");
            args.IsValid = false;
            return;
        } 

        if (endDate != '') {
            if (new Date(startDate) > new Date(endDate)) {
                $(s).text("End date must be after start date.");
                args.IsValid = false;
                return;
            }

    args.IsValid = true;

    return;
    }
```

Here are the textbox and CustomValidators:

```
<td class="StartDateLabel">Date From</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="StartDate" ID="txtFirStartDate" onBlur="DisplayInvalidLabel"/>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cusValFromDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="End date must be after start date." ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDateRange" ControlToValidate="txtFirStartDate" 
        EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup=""SearchGroup" CssClass=""Validator" Display="Dynamic">
    </asp:CustomValidator> 
    <span class="To Label"> to </span>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="EndDate" ID="txtFirstEndDate" onBlur="DisplayInvalidLabel"/>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cusValToDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="End date must be after start date." ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDateRange" ControlToValidate="txtFirstEndDate"
        EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="SearchGroup" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic">
    </asp:CustomValidator> 
</td>
<td class="StartDateLabel">Second Date From</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="StartDate" ID="txtSecondStartStart" ToolTip="This field allows for ranges. See LEGEND" onBlur="DisplayInvalidLabel()"/>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="custSecStartVal" runat="server" ErrorMessage="End date must be after start date." ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDateRange" ControlToValidate="txtSecondStartStart"
        EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="SearchGroup" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic">
    </asp:CustomValidator> 
</td>
<td class="To Label">Second  to</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="EndDate" ID="txtSecondEndDate" ToolTip="This field allows for ranges. See LEGEND" onBlur="DisplayInvalidLabel()"/>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="custSecEndVal" runat="server" ErrorMessage="End date must be after start date." ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDateRange" ControlToValidate="txtSecondEndDate"
        EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="SearchGroup" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic">
    </asp:CustomValidator>
</td>
```

The validation works fine.  When I enter an invalid value the respective error message shows up next to the defined control.  The focus is placed where it needs to be.  However if I tab through the 4 entry boxes when I tab out of the third one ("txtSecondStartDate") if I don't enter anything my message from the "txtFirstStartDate" disappears with the invalid date remaining.  I know it is resseting the validation to true but I am missing where that it is doing that?

That is the same for all the text boxes.  Initially it works but if I click in any other control that has a validator after a couple clicks it clears the messages of the other ones that should remain invalid.  I just can't see where it is happeneing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.  The problem was comming from the "onBlur" event that I have on each input textbox.  I had tied it to another function that was validating so it was causing a mix up when inputs were and weren't happening.